# Parallel call on tcpclient stem.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected

Tags: c#, sockets, parallel-processing, .net-core, tcpclient

I have a single class instance where i am managing login/heartbeat and actual working items packet sending receiving on a tcp client.

Problem is when i try to call ProcessCommand parallel sometime i got error

**System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

```
public class TcpCommunicationManager
{        
    private TcpClient client = null;
    public TcpCommunicationManager(string ip, int port)
    {
        Ip = ip;
        Port = port;
    }



    public SSMIResponse ProcessCommand(SSMIRequest request)
    {

        SSMIResponse response = new SSMIResponse();
        if (request.CmdType == CommandType.Login)
        {
            client = new TcpClient(Ip, Port);             
        }

        response.RequestedCommand = GetCommandTextFromRequest(request);
        byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.RequestedCommand);
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        request.RequestTime = DateTime.Now;

        var result = stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Request Command:" + response.RequestedCommand);
        response.SendSuccess = true;

        var data = new Byte[1024];


            stream.ReadTimeout = 1000 * 5; //5 seconds


            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            var bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            response.ResponseTime = DateTime.Now;
            response.ResponseRawResultPacket = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            ProcessResponseResult(request, response);
            Console.WriteLine("Response Received:" + response.ResponseRawResultPacket + Environment.NewLine);
        return response;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Either the server isn't running, or you are getting a timeout,or the connection already exists.  There are two ways of debugging.  From cmd.exe you can use >Netstat -a which will give all the udp and tcp connections that the status of the connection.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  IN the sniffer check for [FIN] messages which indicate when the connection closes.

Comment: TcpClient isn't meant to be used from multiple threads. Synchronize calls by locking, for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster if you can put your comment in answer then i will accept it as answer. it help me clear my concept.
Thanks